# Rails - Combining values from two dropdown boxes into a single value on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All, I have two dropdown boxes, which are populated from two different database tables and a form with a single submit button. My goal is to concatenate the two values upon form submit and write the single value back to the database into the form associated with the model.

More simply: two dropboxes allowing to select ['red','green','blue'] and ['dog','cat']. The user selects 'red' and 'cat', and the submit button creates a new record 'red-cat' (under the blogname model) as a result.

ENTIRE Form (new.html.erb) code:

```
<%= select("subdomainw1", "blognamew1", Subdomainw1.order("blognamew1 ASC").collect {|p| [ p.blognamew1  ] }, {:prompt => 'Select Adjective'}) %>
<%= select("subdomainw2", "blognamew2", Subdomainw2.order("blognamew2 ASC").collect {|p| [ p.blognamew2  ] }, {:prompt => 'Select Noun'}) %>

<%= simple_form_for (@blogname) do |f| %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

with the associated controller *def create* being:

```
 def create
    @blogname = Blogname.new(params[:blogname])
    respond_to do |format|
      @blogname.blogname = ?? THIS SHOULD BE A CONCATENATION OF THE VALUES FROM ABOVE SELECTS
        if @blogname.save
        format.html { redirect_to @blogname, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, the Rails way would be to do it in your model and keep your controllers skinny.

I think the most common way in rails you'll see this done is a callback. So, for this example you could set up a before_validation (or perhaps before_create if you don't want it to be changed if the blog is edited) call back in your mode, and assign your blogname from the two other attributes.

```
model.rb

before_validation :generate_blogname

def generate_blogname
   self.blogname ||= "#{blognamew1}-#{blognamew2}".parameterize
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
 controller.rb

 def create
    @blogname = Blogname.new(params[:blogname])

    respond_to do |format|
       if @blogname.save
        format.html { redirect_to @blogname, notice: 'Blog was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
 end
```

The parameterize method will make this work for subdomains by taking out special characters.  The model shouldn't probably be called blogname, it should probably be a table blog with an attribute of name. So @blog = Blog.new, then @blog.name = "Two Subdomain Values"

Comment: Thanks Kombo, a little more hand-holding is required.. How does self.slug get assigned to the blogname field as a new record? In my original code i've placed a '??' - and tried to replace those with self.slug, slug, blogname. None of these resulted in a new record with the field blogname populated with the selected dropboxes' values..

Comment: Oops, sorry about .slug, I just copy-pasted it and missed that. The slug is going to be your blogname, I changed the code to reflect this. My bad.

Comment: This is the skinny controller vs. fat model design. It says your controller should be doing nothing but moving people around, the logic should be all in your model. So remove the ?? line from the controller, and the callback will do the assigning before, or around whatever you tell it to (in my example before the validation). http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Oy, not working.. I verified the code setup 'works' by commenting out the self.blogname line in the model and added a simple self.blogname = "trytrytry_db".. That gets written fine (as a record in blogname table). However, your original line returns *undefined local variable or method `subdomainw1' for #<Blogname:0xb57aad4>*..

Comment: Oops, think you just need to replace subdomainw1 with blognamew1, and subdomainw2 with blogname2.

Comment: so, yep, i should have picked up on that.. however, still getting the same exception (with blognamew1 now..); What bothers me is how does the model 'know' what the user selected in the form, as it's concatenating the two dropdown selections. We're not passing these variables anywhere into the model, so how would this callback work?